# convert_timezone does not make sense with timestampdiff in snowflake sql

Tags: sql

```
select 
   convert_timezone('America/Los_Angeles', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),
   convert_timezone('America/Chicago', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),
   timediff(hour, 
    convert_timezone('America/Los_Angeles', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()),
    convert_timezone('America/Chicago', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())
    ) as a;
```

the first two columns of this show times with 2 hour difference, but last column always shows 0, why?

Answer (score 1):

convert_timezone doesn't change the underlying value e.g. midnight GMT is midnight GMT regardless of the timezone you are in. Changing from LA to Chicago is not adding 2 hours to the physical value being stored - so the time difference between 2 identical times will always be 0 regardless of the timezones you choose to display them in